How to generate the API of a websocket request and response using Postman?
I have a Node.js application that functions as a WebSocket server. I can establish a WebSocket connection between my server and Postman, and Postman can receive the response. Now, I need to document the API of this interaction so that the front-end can utilize it to interact with the WebSocket server. Upon reviewing the Postman panel, I did not find any option or button to export the API (similar to what we do for HTTP requests). What should I do? How can I export the API of a WebSocket connection?
